# Unable to connect Orbeon Remote Server using Orbeon-Auth + Tomcat 8

Tags: basic-authentication, orbeon

I want to connect to the Orbeon Remote Server which runs on Tomcat 8, using orbeon-auth application which was provided by Orbeon.

1. I have created the users and roles in remote server
   tomcat-users.xml.
2. Having default realm in server.xml.
3. Added below properties in properties-local.xml.

```html
<!-- Security Settings -->
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.method" value="container" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.container.roles" value="orbeon-service" />
<property as="xs:anyURI" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="authorizer" value="/orbeon-auth" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.state" value="none" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.forward-headers" value="Cookie" />
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.forward-cookies" value=" JSESSIONID
       iPlanetDirectoryPro" />
<property as="xs:integer" name="oxf.http.so-timeout" value="0" />
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.http.exceptions" value="true" />

<property as="xs:string" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="page-public-methods" value="GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE" />
<property as="xs:string" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="service-public-methods" value="GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE" />

<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri" value="http://localhost:8080/forms" />
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.uri" value="http://localhost:8080/forms/fr/service/exist" />
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri" value="http://localhost:8080/forms/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr" />
```

- And my web.xml contains BASIC authentication with role based configurations.

```html
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>No Restriction</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/fr/service/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/fr/style/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/fr/login</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/xforms-server</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>With Restriction</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Portal</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>orbeon-service</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But, with all these configurations, when I try to give the orbeon-admin credentials in the local server, it's unable to authenticate, instead provides this log.

```
xf:submission for submission id: fr-default-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 401

PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/service/persistence/form", status-code: "401"}
```

Can any one please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "Orbeon Remote Server"? Do you have 2 instances of Orbeon Forms, one local and one remote? Are you trying to use the Form Runner Home Page remote server operations (http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/home-page.html#remote-server-operations)?